# Authorize.net ARB API Integration Question

Tags: authorize.net, credit-card, authorize.net-arb

I'm integrating with Authorize.net's ARB API.  Authorize.net processes their transactions at a certain time everyday, so when people create a subscription, their transaction is not real time.

I am creating a subscription based model, does their API tell me whether their CC has been processed?  Or should I put a delay on the access to my site until they have processed all the ARB transactions that day.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You should be charging their first subscription payment via the [AIM API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/aim/). This will give you instant feedback as to whether or not the payment was good. Assuming it was successful you then can use ARB to create their subscription by setting the start date to be the date of their next scheduled payment.

This serves two purposes:

- If the card is bad you know immediately and can have the user provide a new card while they are still on your website. Once they leave your site it gets much more difficult to get them back to correct it.
- You can give them instant access without worrying about whether or not their card is approved or not.

FYI, you can use [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/) to determine the status of payments made via ARB.